# Scrollbar missing when page contents are refreshed

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have this winforms app.  When the content of the page is changed, the panel containing the old information is disposed, and a new panel gets displayed. When I run at a lower resolution of 1280x720 and switch content of the panel that vertical scrollbar is missing.  When I try to move the window around, the vertical scroll bar appears.
I tried calling Invalidate() and Refresh() to force the window to repaint but it's not working.  Can anyone help.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Application.DoEvents()` when you try to refresh:

```
private void ResolutionChangeUpdate() 
{
    frm.Invalidate();
    frm.Refresh();
    frm.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: I tried Application.DoEvents(), but it didn't work.  Is there anything I am missing?